# Touching empty space under a ListView

Tags: android

How can I make the empty space (if it exists) watch for the touch events?

I don't want any special area for that, I just want to add functionality to the empty space under a ListView if it's already there.

Answer (score 2):

Putting an empty LinearLayout with the :width and :height set up to the space underneath the listView can have a onTouchListener added to it, but will appear blank.

Comment: Is there a way to know how large the empty space is under a ListView? Or I would have to set a fixed value?